# Counting parent and child rows from sequelize association

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, associations

I am new to sequelize i am trying to get comments and the replies to those comments by hasMany association and have to count the parent comments and the replies to each comment that i am getting

I am using sequelize findAndCountAll to count the parent comment rows which works fine now counting replies of each comment i am using

```
attributes:{include: [[mysql.sequelize.fn("COUNT", mysql.sequelize.col("comment.comment_id")), "Count"]]}
```

Which count the replies of the first comment but does get gives the rest of the parent comments

```
model
    const comment = model.comment;

    comment.hasMany(comment,
        {
            foreignKey: 'parentCommentId',
            as: "replies"
        });

query
function findWhere(where, pagination){

    return mysql.comment.findAndCountAll({
        where,
        offset: pagination.offset,
        limit: pagination.count,

        // attributes:{include: [[mysql.sequelize.fn("COUNT", mysql.sequelize.col("comment.comment_id")), "Count"]]},

        include: [{
            model: mysql.comment,
            as: "replies",
            offset: 0,
            limit: 1
        }]

    });
}
```

This is the reply that it gives

```
{
    "count": 10,
    "rows": [
        {
            "commentId": 2,
            "userId": 7,
            "postId": 1,
            "mediaId": null,
            "commentText": "2 Updated Wao amazing post 13",
            "parentCommentId": null,
            "createdAt": "2019-07-01T05:20:00.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2019-07-04T02:35:49.000Z",
            "Count": 10,
            "replies": [
                {
                    "commentId": 4,
                    "userId": 7,
                    "postId": null,
                    "mediaId": null,
                    "commentText": "Wao amazing post",
                    "parentCommentId": 2,
                    "createdAt": "2019-07-02T04:08:29.000Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2019-07-02T04:08:29.000Z"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Which is wrong as it does not shows the rest of the parent comments

The issue is in this

```
attributes:{include: [[mysql.sequelize.fn("COUNT", mysql.sequelize.col("comment.comment_id")), "Count"]]}
```

Answer (score 0):

added beforeCount hook inside the DB connection file this snippet will fix the wrong count issue in findAndCountAll()

```
sequelize.addHook("beforeCount", function (options) {
  const includeAvailable = options.include && options.find((item) => item["where"]);
  if (this._scope.include && this._scope.include.length > 0) {
    options.distinct = true;
    options.col =
      this._scope.col || options.col || `"${this.options.name.singular}".id`;
  }
  const whereSymbols = includeAvailable
    ? Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(includeAvailable["where"]).length
    : 0;
  const whereString = includeAvailable
    ? JSON.stringify(includeAvailable["where"]).length
    : 0;
  const whereObject = whereSymbols > 0 ? whereSymbols : whereString > 2 ? 1 : 0;
  if (whereObject === 0 && options.include && options.include.length > 0) {
    options.include = null;
  }
});
```